# Calculate set of pair by taking one value from each set

Tags: java, algorithm, set

I'm tring to calculate possible number of pair, that can be made by taking value from both two set. No one set repitation. I'm also trying to implement it using **Java** Set. But I'm stuck at logic, How to count such possible combination.

Problem example:

```
Input:
Set 1: [0, 1, 4]
Set 2: [2, 3]
Set None: []
```

Here, Possible pair combination are [0,2] , [0,3] , [1,2] , [1,3] , [4,2] , [4,3]

```
Output:
6 combination to choose pair by taking one value from each set
```

> Here is Code:

```
static Set<Integer> countryOne = new HashSet();
static Set<Integer> countryTwo = new HashSet();
static Set<Integer> countryNone = new HashSet();

static int journeyToMoon(int n, int[][] astronaut) {
    ///Separating diffrent country from input
    countryOne.add(astronaut[0][0]); countryOne.add(astronaut[0][1]);
    for(int i=1; i<astronaut.length; i++){
        boolean countryCheckFlag = false;
        for(int j=0; j<astronaut[i].length; j++){
            if(countryOne.contains(astronaut[i][j])){
                countryCheckFlag = true;
            }
        }
        if(countryCheckFlag){countryOne.add(astronaut[i][0]); countryOne.add(astronaut[i][1]);}
        else {countryTwo.add(astronaut[i][0]); countryTwo.add(astronaut[i][1]);}
    }

    ///Separating country which not present in input
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(!countryOne.contains(i) && !countryTwo.contains(i))
            countryNone.add(i);
    }

    //Now i have two diffrent set

    return 0;
}
```

Input might be diffrent at a certain level, like this

```
Input:
Set 1: [0, 2]
Set 2: []
Set None: [1, 3]
```

Here, Possible pair combination are [0,1] , [0,3] , [2,1] , [2,3] as like before, But as it is it Set None, so it will create set between Set None as extra, like [1,3]

```
Output:
5 combination to choose pair by taking one value from each set
```

Here Might be Answer like, Total combination = (Possible combination of set one and set two with product) + (Possible combination of set 1 and set 2 with set none each) + (All possible combination of Set None with diffrent value)

If so, How to calculate it. Input range will be between 1 to 10^5. Thanks.

Comment: How does your logic look at the moment? Did you write some code?

Comment: yes. The problem is much bigger. Now at this moment i have two `Set<Integer> set1, set2` holding values like input described in question.

Comment: That’s a good start. Please edit your question and show us the code you are stuck with so we can give you concrete help.

Comment: okay. sure.. I'll add it soon.

Comment: Okay, what is your **concrete** problem now? Why don’t you just use `set.size()` and multiply the sizes of the two sets with each other?

Comment: Yes that will work maybe, I've added some more details, but not sure if that work.. Will you please check it. I'm forgetting details, so editing multiple times. I hope this time it'll be full clear to you.

Comment: Multiplying two set working. But whats about "All possible combination of Set None with diffrent value".

Comment: Please give some more example inputs and outputs? Why is there suddenly a third set (Set None)? It is very hard to answer a question when you incrementally change your question.

Comment: I'm really sorry about it. Your first comment working. But How to calculate it? If `[1,2,3,4]` is a set, what is the max combination with two diffrent value from `[1,2,3,4]`, like`[1,2],[1,3],[1,4], [2,3],[2,4], ....`. We cant take `[1,1]` because both same value, and also `[2,1]` as `[1,2]` already counted. You can it on answer section. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the total number of combinations you can simply use

```
int a = set1.size() * set2.size();
```

To calculate the total number of pairs of `n` elements you can use the formula `(n*n - n) / 2`, so in your example this might be

```
int x = setNone.size();
int b = (x * x - x) / 2
```